# UITableViewCell indentationLevel doesn't work in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I've a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` and I use `indentationLevel` for move the content to the right.
In iOS 7 all works fine, but in iOS 8 when I set an `indentationLevel > 0` the table view doesn't render the cell and the interface freezes. The only solution is to quit the app.
If I stay in debug I can see that the memory used from the app continuously increase and that the CPU is at 99%.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";
    TreeTableViewCell *cell = (TreeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;

    FolderSection *aFolderSection = self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.section];
    FolderNode *aFolderNode = (FolderNode *)aFolderSection.folderNodes[indexPath.row];

    cell.indentationWidth = 20.0f;
    cell.indentationLevel = aFolderNode.level;

    // set up the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Ideas ?

Comment: Before setting the `indentationLevel`, can you try `NSLog`ing `aFolderNode.level`? I think it might be a problem with how that is generated.

Comment: No, `aFolderNode.level` is right

Answer (score 5):

It seems that iOS > 6 lays the Views before the methods for indentation configuration are called. Change the code in your CustomCell.swift to this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.indentationWidth = 30.0
    self.indentationLevel = 0
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let indentPoints = CGFloat(self.indentationLevel) * self.indentationWidth
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints, self.contentView.frame.origin.y,self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,self.contentView.frame.size.height)
}
```

to call them appropriately. And afterwards in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
...
cell.indentationLevel = 1 // Your indentation level
```

Comment: Works great on iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have another problem, `indentationLevel` and `indentationWidth` both work in iOS 8 as expected.

I would try:

- Removing the call to access your dataSource and assigning `indentationLevel` to a static value (if that works, you have a problem
  with your dataSource to debug).
- Using a vanilla `UITableViewCell` to make sure it is not a problem with your `TreeTableViewCell` subclass.
- Verify all of your Storyboard setup is correct (assuming you're using Storyboard and cell prototypes). Make sure your prototype cell, in fact, uses the CellID you're dequeueing (`CustomCellReuseID` in your case).